# Inheriting variables from a python class without using init or the class name of the parent

Tags: python, class, variables, inheritance

I am using kivy just to give you a bit of context...

but what I want is to be able to call class variables from another class.
without init the classes

```
class FIRST-CLASS(Screen):
    variables
    def functions():
       pass

class SECOND-CLASS(Screen,CLASSIFIERS):
    *i would say FIRST-CLASS.variable but i cant...
     i need a way to say parent.variable.
```

Comment: FIRST-CLASS *isn't* a parent of SECOND-CLASS the way you've written things. And why do you think you can't say FIRST-CLASS.variable? (Besides all the invalid name choices.)

Comment: All caps for class def causes eye pain.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my preferred method:

Use `global`.

You can use `global` to make the variable global.

```
class Parent():
  # You need to put the global before the declaration of the variable
  global var
  var = 'EXAMPLE'

class Secondary():
  var2 = var
```